# ASP.net C# Bind Gridview using a button inside modalpopup

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, modalpopup

Codes of the button inside modalpopup (

```
protected void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(gvItemAssignment.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
        con.Close();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand delete = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblAssignment SET AssignDeleteStatus = 'Deleted' WHERE AssignID = " + index + "", con);
        delete.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        dgvItemAssignment.DataBind();
        btnDelete_ModalPopupExtender.Hide();
    }
```

Modalpopup

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnDelete_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="btnNo" 
            PopupControlID="Panel3" TargetControlID="btnRemove">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

btnRemove for calling (no codes inside)

Main problem is the `Databind` on btnYes is not working. `Gridview` is outside. ill click remove button then the popup shows. Then click btnYes inside, doing all the codes except databind, then popup hides. Tried doing `this.Databind();` and also `IsPostback` on the `PageLoad`. Very much appreciated if you could help me with this. Stuck in a while.

Comment: What is the exactly error?

Comment: there are no errors. its just that dgvItemAssignment.DataBind(); is not working.

Comment: if you are saying doesnt bind, maybe  dgvItemAssignment is empty

Comment: It is not. Actually i do bind for edit, add, delete using almost same code. Chose delete because its the shortest code. Thats just the problem. Databind not working.